# How to use lapply to count unique values from a list in r

Tags: r, count, bioinformatics, lapply, biomart

I have asked a similar question on here before about how to count unique values from a dataframe, but I need to use "lapply" instead because the way I used previously doesn't work or I cant get it to work with a list. I have also been told the using one of the apply functions would be better.

This represents my data:

```
species1 <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a","a","a","b", "b", "b"), var_2 = c("c","c","d", "d", "e", "e"))

species2 <- data.frame(var_1 = c("f","f","f","g", "g", "g"), var_2 = c("h","h","i", "i", "j", "j"))

all_species <- list()

all_species[["species1"]] <- species1
all_species[["species2"]] <- species2
```

I want to use lapply to get the number of unique rows for each of my lists, for example, I need an output like:

```
count_all_species <- list()
count_all_species[["species1"]] <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a", "b"), unique_number = c("2", "2"))
```

Then the same for the second list using the "lapply" function

Comment: Unique number should be 3, right?

Comment: Sorry the number of unique rows based on both var_1 and var_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  We loop through the `list` of `data.frame` (with `map`), grouped by 'var_1', `summarise` to get the number of distinct elements in 'var_2' (`n_distinct`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(all_species, ~ .x %>%
                     group_by(var_1) %>% 
                     summarise(unique_number = n_distinct(var_2)))
```

---

Or use the `distinct` after looping through the `list` and then do a `count`

```
map(all_species, ~ .x %>% 
                     distinct() %>% 
                     dplyr::count(var_1))
```

#### Update

If the variable name changes, then we can use position in `summarise_at`

```
map(all_species, ~ .x %>%
                     group_by(var_1) %>% 
                     summarise_at(1, n_distinct))
```

---

Or another option is to convert the column name string to a symbol (`rlang::sym`) and then do the evaluation (`!!`)

```
map(all_species, ~ .x %>%
             group_by(var_1) %>% 
             summarise(unique_number = n_distinct(!! rlang::sym(names(.x)[2]))))
```

Comment: This works for the example provided above, what I didn't, but should have included is that the var_2 name changes slightly in my real life example e.g. species1, var_2 = hsapiens_gene_name and species2, var_2 = mmusculus_gene_name. This is why I would rather use lapply so I can use paste0 e.g. lapply(species_name_vector, function(s) paste0(s, "_geen_name"))

Comment: @JackDean  If the name changes, then you can use `summarise_at`

Comment: Thanks that works great! I'm assuming the "1" in `summarise_at` means summarise based on the first column?

Comment: @JackDean The reason is that there is a group_by and mutate_at will consider indexing from the next column i.e. if there is no `group_by`, the column 2nd will be indexed with 2 `map(all_species, ~ .x  %>% summarise_at(2, n_distinct))`

Comment: @JackDean BTW, i don't know if this indexing would change in the future or not, but it is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

`Table` would be a simple base-R solution.

```
lapply(all_species, function(x) {
 apply(x, 2, table) 
  }
)
```